# Failure to load fullscreen image in Android S4

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have image gallery which shows a number of images and once user clicks on one of the images, it supposes to be displayed. Once I click on a image to view in full screen in Samsung S4 phone, it's throwing below errors. But, the same set coding is working fine with emulator to display image. Please can anyone help me...?

```
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694): Process: com.version_one.madsports, PID: 12694
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:703)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:679)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:446)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at com.madsports.classes.FullScreenImageAdapter.instantiateItem(FullScreenImageAdapter.java:58)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1053)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2533)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2213)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1236)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6471)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-04 23:03:32.704: E/AndroidRuntime(12694):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load bitmap/image AS-IS is not good idea, because it can be much larger than you actually need to display on screen. To start you could read this good article [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)